# How to redirect a root sub-folder to a sub-domain using htaccess rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect all the links of a subfolder to a new subdomain, so for example:

`example.com/sso/` redirects to `sso.example.com`

`example.com/sso/login` redirects to `sso.example.com/login`

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^/sso/(.*) http://sso.example.com/$1 [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Try removing the leading slash in ^/sso/(.*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written as per your shown samples. Please clear your browser cache after putting these rules in your htaccess file. Added few more options to your attempt, like to match sso ignore case mode. Added `L` flag to stop rule's processing after this, so that shouldn't conflict with other rules.

Also `.` in `example.com` should be escaped to make it treated as a literal character.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(sso|SSO)/(.*)$ http://sso.example.com/$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: The condition %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sso is unnecessary because the same check is performed by the RewriteRule

Comment: @Thakkie, I have removed the condition now and placed a regex to possibly match small or upper case of sso in rule itself.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for your help. There's just a small problem because it's redirecting to `sso.example.com/sso` but because it's masking the old URL. I'm trying to get it to reflect just the sub directories that fall after sso/ so for example to try and get `example.com/sso` to `sso.example.com` and `example.com/sso/login` to `sso.example.com/login`

Comment: @Joboy2212, sorry for that a typo happened, could you please place these rules in your htaccess, clear your browser cache and try again? Let me know how it goes then?